# Automatic File Uploader to Website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, web, web-crawler, image-uploading

I have a website with a form to upload files. I want to automatically sign in and upload image files once a changes are scene on my local folder on my computer. Can any guidance be provided in the matter.

Comment: You may have to write a native application to do this as such functionality would be a security risk and is most likely not supported by common browsers.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I am a bit new at things. What approach will work?

Comment: The Site  for local files on your computer  is not the same origin as your website, and in order to prevent XSS (cross-site scripting), the only way a file can be sent to a website is by the user selecting a file natively.  Theres no way to poll the local disk of a machine from a website or from javascript in order to determine if a file has changed (at least not that I know of)

Comment: I want the program on the computer to check for changes in folder/files and upload them. Nothing to do with the website

Comment: Oh I see.. that makes things a bit clearer...

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you can write a task for this purpose, which can run lets say every hour and check if any changes are made in directory then upload these files on you app.

Comment: Any detail on how could I write one?

Comment: Yes sure, please have a look at `Sidekiq gem`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of system you are working on but you could do something like this. If you are on a linux system you could use the [watch](http://beerpla.net/2007/08/04/watch-a-useful-linux-command-you-may-have-never-heard-of/) command to track the activity of the directory of choice. The what you could do is use something like [Mechanize](http://crabonature.pl/posts/23-automation-with-mechanize-and-ruby) in a ruby script that gets triggered by the watch command that will then go and submit the form and upload the file for you by selecting the file with the latest creation date.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that it says ruby on rails in the post, but this answer is just as legitimate as writing a solution in Ruby (and a bit easier/faster)

Using Qt C++ to do this, then you could do something like this:

(untested, you'll have to make adjustments for your exact situation)

Overview of Code:

- Create a program that loops on a Timer every 20 minutes and goes through the entire directory that you specify with `WATCH_DIR`, and if it finds any files in that directory which were modified in between the time that the loop last ran (or after the program starts but before the first loop is run), then it uploads that exact file to whatever URL you specify with  `UPLOAD_URL`

Then create a file called `AutoUploader.pro` and a file called `main.cpp`

---

***AutoUploader.pro***

```
QT += core network
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = AutoUploader
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

---

***main.cpp***

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>
#include <QDir>
#include <QDirIterator>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QHash>

#define WATCH_DIR "/home/lenny/images"
#define UPLOAD_URL "http://127.0.0.1/upload.php"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainLoop loop(WATCH_DIR);
    return a.exec();
}

class MainLoop : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public: 
    MainLoop(QString _watch_directory = qApp->applicationDirPath()) {
        watch_directory = _watch_directory;


        // the  ACTION="" part of the upload form
        website_upload_url = UPLOAD_URL;

        /*  20 minutes
         20 * 60 * 1000 = num of milliseconds that makes up 
        20 mins =     1200000 ms */
        QTimer::singleShot(1200000, this, SLOT(check_for_updates()));

        /* this will stop any file modified before you ran this program from 
         being uploaded so it wont upload all of the files at runtime */
        program_start_time = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
    }


    QDateTime program_start_time;
    QString watch_directory;
    QString website_upload_url;

    // hash table to store all of the last modified times for each file 
    QHash<QString, QDateTime> last_modified_time;
    ~MainLoop() { qApp->exit(); }

public slots:
    void check_for_updates() {
        QDirIterator it(QDir(watch_directory));

        /* loop through all file in directory */
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            QFileInfo info(it.next());

            /* check to see if the files modified time is ahead of 
               program_start_time  */
            if (info.lastModified.msecsTo(program_start_time) < 1) {
                upload_file(info.absoluteFilePath());
            }
        }
        /* set program_start_time to the current time to catch stuff next
           time around and then start a timer to repeat this command in
           20 minutes */
        program_start_time = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
        QTimer::singleShot(1200000, this, SLOT(check_for_updates()));
    }


   /*  upload file  code came from 
      https://forum.qt.io/topic/11086/solved-qnetworkaccessmanager-uploading-files/2 
    */

    void upload_file(QString filename) {
        QNetworkAccessManager *am = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
        QString path(filename);

        // defined with UPLOAD_URL
        QNetworkRequest request(QUrl(website_upload_url)); 

        QString bound="margin"; //name of the boundary
        //according to rfc 1867 we need to put this string here:
        QByteArray data(QString("--" + bound + "\r\n").toAscii());
        data.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"action\"\r\n\r\n");
        data.append("upload.php\r\n");
        data.append("--" + bound + "\r\n"); //according to rfc 1867
        data.append(QString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded\"; filename=\"%1\"\r\n").arg(QFileInfo(filename).fileName()));     
        data.append(QString("Content-Type: image/%1\r\n\r\n").arg(QFileInfo(filename).suffix())); //data type
        QFile file(path);
        if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
            return;
        data.append(file.readAll()); //let's read the file
        data.append("\r\n");
        data.append("--" + bound + "--\r\n"); 
        request.setRawHeader(QString("Content-Type").toAscii(),QString("multipart/form-data; boundary=" + bound).toAscii());
        request.setRawHeader(QString("Content-Length").toAscii(), QString::number(data.length()).toAscii());
        this->reply = am->post(request,data);

        connect(this->reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(replyFinished()));   
    }

    void replyFinished() {
        /*  perform some code here whenever a download finishes */
    }

};
```

---

Before running this program, make sure to read through it completely and make the necessary changes by reading the comments and the post -- also you may have to install the qt framework depending on your platform

Anyways, the final step is to run `qmake` to create the project makefile and finally, `make` to build the binary.

Obviously the last steps are different depending on what system you are using.

... This program will continue to run... essentially forever until you close it.... uploading changed files every 20 minutes

Hope this helps...